# How to get the date from "date_select" and verify it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a beginner of ruby.
I want to get dates from forms and validate them in subclasses, but I don't know how to implement them. Maybe I don't know how to get dates from hash. Please help me.

```
# HTML
<%= form_with model: @order, scope: :order, url: update_signed_in_show_employer_url(order.employer, order_id: order.id) , method: :put, class: '' do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>start date:</label>
    <% if order.signed_at.present? %>
    <%= f.date_select :started_at, {default: order.signed_at}, { class: 'form-control m-b' } %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

```
# controller
def update_signed_in_show
  @employer = Employer.find(params[:id])
  logger.debug "singned_params: #{signed_params}"
  @order = Order::Signed.find(params[:order_id])

  ......
end
```

```
# class Order::Signed < Order
validate :check_started_at
def check_started_at
  if self.started_at.present? && self.ended_at.present?
    if self.started_at.to_datetime < self.signed_at.to_datetime
      errors.add :started_at, 'xoxoxoxoxo.......'
    end
  end
end
```

In the controller, I can read the parameters in the form.
hash:
{"started_at(1i)"=>"2019", "started_at(2i)"=>"4", "started_at(3i)"=>"17", "ended_at(1i)"=>"2022", "ended_at(2i)"=>"4", "ended_at(3i)"=>"17", "remark_of_signed"=>"", "status"=>"signed"}

I wanted to validate in subclasses, but I received an error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `to_datetime' for nil:NilClass):
app/models/order/signed.rb:20:in`check_started_at'

Comment: You're never assigning the parameters you get in the controller to the model in the code you provided. In the model validation you're checking if started_at and ended_at are present, but then comparing started_at and signed_at. signed_at is nil and throws an error.

If you just assign the hash to the attributes of the model, rails will parse the hash to the proper datetime value for you, no need to call .to_datetime on it afterwards.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have used the method you provided to achieve the goal. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Siim Liiser for his help, I have been able to verify it successfully.

```
# Order::Entered < Order
validate :check_ended_at

def check_ended_at
  if self.started_at.present? && self.ended_at.present?
    if self.ended_at < (self.started_at + signed_years_count.year)
      errors.add :started_at, 'error message...'
    end
  end
end
```